# score does not reset when game is lauched again

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

I am building a simple soccer penalty shootout. Once the ball hits the goal the score is set to 1 and this score is saved. The game resets by itself. If the game has been reset automatically then the score should be kept. The question is that when the users exit out of the game and restart manually the previous score has not reset. I want the score to reset if this happens.

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class Goalcollide : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text scoretext;  // Displays the score on the text
    public Text goaltext;  // to output goal message once the goal has been scored
    public int counter = 0;  // Socre counter.

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("counter") != 0)
        {
            counter = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("count");  
        }
    }
    void Start()
    {
        counter = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("count");
        //counter = 0;

        //scoretext.text = counter.ToString();
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisionINFO)
    {
        if (collisionINFO.collider.name == "Goal Post")
        {
            counter += 1;  // Increments score each time
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("count", counter);   // Saves the score
            scoretext.text = counter.ToString();    // Displayed score
            goaltext.text = "GOALLL";  // Displayed the message.
            FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame();  // The game is reset
        }

        if (collisionINFO.collider.name != "Plane")
        {
            FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you uncomment `//counter = 0;`?

Comment: Can't you just `counter = 0` and `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("count", counter);` right before the player exits? This should save 0 as counter and therefor reset the counter as counter get's loaded next time

Answer (score 0):

## Stop using `PlayerPrefs`

If you want the score to save only during a program execution session, then *you shouldn't store it in PlayerPrefs.*

You shouldn't be storing game state in `PlayerPrefs` in the first place (its for things like audio volume level or preferred control scheme: user *preferences*) and in the second place, it is a location that persists data between runs.

By not wanting your score data to persist between runs you've stored it in the wrongest place.

Do this instead:

```
public class GameData {
   public static int score;
}
```

You now have a publicly accessible static variable that will persist across scene load boundaries but only exists in RAM and not on disk.